# Google+ API feed does not update

Tags: google-api, google-plus

There seem to be an issue with Google+ API.

Data returned by `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/<user_id>/activities/public` request does not contain a few latest posts. The feed does not update for at least 24 hours for a one particular user. Posts posted on the account are public and are visible via `https://plus.google.com/<user_id>` link.

Is there a way to raise this issue with Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ API bugs can be reported in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).